# Python pandas keep first columns' order unchanged while second col sort by ascending order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I want to keep the column infoid order unchanged but sort date in increasing order(acsending)
Is that possible?

```
statisticsdate  infoid 
20230108      46726004
20230106      46726004
20230108      46725082
20230107      46725082
20230108      46725081
20230108      46724162
20230108      46720662
```

should be like:

```
statisticsdate  infoid 
20230106      46726004
20230108      46726004
20230107      46725082
20230108      46725082
20230108      46725081
20230108      46724162
20230108      46720662
```

Answer (score 2):

If possible sorting `infoid` descending and `infoid` ascending use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) only:

```
df = df.sort_values(['infoid','statisticsdate'], ascending=[False, True], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   statisticsdate    infoid
0        20230106  46726004
1        20230108  46726004
2        20230107  46725082
3        20230108  46725082
4        20230108  46725081
5        20230108  46724162
6        20230108  46720662
```

First idea is sorting per groups by custom lambda function with `sort=False` parameter for no sorting groups, solution is slow if larger DataFrame:

```
df['statisticsdate'] = (df.groupby('infoid', sort=False, group_keys=False)['statisticsdate']
                          .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values())
                          .to_numpy())
print (df)
   statisticsdate    infoid
0        20230106  46726004
1        20230108  46726004
2        20230107  46725082
3        20230108  46725082
4        20230108  46725081
5        20230108  46724162
6        20230108  46720662
```

Or you can convert `infoid` to ordered Categorical and sorting by both columns:

```
df['statisticsdate'] = (df.assign(infoid = pd.Categorical(df['infoid'],
                                                          ordered=True, 
                                                          categories=df['infoid'].unique()))
                          .sort_values(['infoid','statisticsdate']))['statisticsdate']
print (df)
   statisticsdate    infoid
0        20230108  46726004
1        20230106  46726004
2        20230108  46725082
3        20230107  46725082
4        20230108  46725081
5        20230108  46724162
6        20230108  46720662
```

If some groups are not sorted is necessary convert `infoid` to consecutive groups and then sorting by both columns:

```
print (df)
   statisticsdate    infoid
0        20230108  46726004
1        20230106  46726004
2        20230108  46725082
3        20230107  46725082
4        20230108  46725081
5        20230108  46724162
6        20230108  46720662
7        20230108  46726004 <- not sorted group 46726004
8        20230106  46726004


df['statisticsdate'] = (df.assign(infoid = df['infoid'].ne(df['infoid'].shift()).cumsum())
              .sort_values(['infoid','statisticsdate'], ignore_index=True)['statisticsdate'])
print (df)
   statisticsdate    infoid
0        20230106  46726004
1        20230108  46726004
2        20230107  46725082
3        20230108  46725082
4        20230108  46725081
5        20230108  46724162
6        20230108  46720662
7        20230106  46726004
8        20230108  46726004
```

Comment: df['statisticsdate'] = df.groupby('infoid', sort=False, group_keys=False)['statisticsdate'].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values()).to_numpy()
I think this one looks good

Comment: @cloudscomputes - `groupby` is unfortunately slow, so it was reason for added another solutions (without groupby)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```py
>>> df.groupby('id').transform(lambda x: x.sort_values()).join(df['id'])

       date        id
0  20230106  46726004
1  20230108  46726004
2  20230107  46725082
3  20230108  46725082
4  20230108  46725081
5  20230108  46724162
6  20230108  46720662
```

Or without a join:

```py
>>> df.set_index('id').groupby('id').transform(lambda x: x.sort_values()).reset_index()

         id      date
0  46726004  20230106
1  46726004  20230108
2  46725082  20230107
3  46725082  20230108
4  46725081  20230108
5  46724162  20230108
6  46720662  20230108
```

Comment: The second one is interesting!